# Redistributing aws elasticsearch primary shard content into two equal sized shard in same existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, sharding, aws-elasticsearch

I need a way that whenever shard size increases from a given size limit, I need to redistribute that shard's data into two equal-size shards by adding one more shard and transfer half of the original size exceeded shard's data into newly created shard in the same index.

I have got the shard state like following, but need help find a way to distribute the data

```
{
    "index": "public",  
    "shard": "0",   
    "store": "20GB" 
}
```

P.S. I have tried **Split Index API** [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html) but this doesn't serve the purpose as it requires a new non-existing index and it cannot do the magic on the existing index, like in the above example index 'public' need to be the same but shard should increase and distribute data among themselves

Comment: Quick question: why does the index need to stay the same ?

Comment: My only purpose was to keep the index name the same as there are some API calls for that particular named index let's say in the above example name is 'public'. Secondly, when this approach (which now seems not possible) will keep on creating splitted shards whenever size increases, so the other shards remain untouched.

Comment: Why not leveraging an alias instead? `public` would be the alias, but behind that alias you are free to manage your index as you see fit. Anytime you need to reorganize your shards, you can split the original index into another index with more shards and when done you just switch the alias to the new index...

Comment: yeah, would be doing something like that.

Comment: Then it's definitely possible and the Split API is exactly what you need :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you can't change the primary shards of elasticsearch index on the same index, this is because if your routing and location depend on the number of primary shards(created at the index creation time).

And if you change it, elasticsearch will have to change the routing algorithm and distribute the data again to evenly distribute the data in all the shards(including replica). **Doing the above on a distributed large-scale stateful application is not an easy feat and elasticsearch as of now doesn't support it.**

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, what could be the best way to make sure shard size does not exceed let's say 20GB, and in case of more data index adds new shard?

Comment: @A-P, its a tricky part and related to capacity planning, and identifying the optimal shard size and number according to specific use-cases depends on various trade-off, I would strongly advise you to read https://opster.com/blogs/elasticsearch-shards-and-replicas-getting-started-guide/#:~:text=While%20each%20shard%20contains%20a,event%20of%20a%20node%20failure. and https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/search-latency-guide/

Comment: @A-P above blogs were written by me and should give you some good understanding about shards and replicas which are the backbone of ES, but to answer your question in a comment again, it's not possible and you need to create a new index with a new number of primary shards and there are various ways to do it and if you are looking for size-based, ILM will be the best choice(as it will automatically rollover to new index).

Comment: Still thinking that the Split API is exactly what @A-P needs, provided he hides everything behind aliases... Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add a shard without reindexing (but you can add a replica)
If part of your data is readonly, and you can activate a basic licence,(probably not in aws) you can define an ILM.

In Open Distro, you can use the equivalent :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html

Comment: IMHO OP intention is not to use the replica shards as he mentioned to split based on shard size, which replica shard will not address :)

Comment: yes that's why he should use a ISM or ILM

Comment: But he wants to do it on the same index, as mentioned in his question `new non-existing index and it cannot do the magic on the existing index` :)

Comment: no you're right. it's not possible on the same index

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason, I didn't include ILM or reindex or shrink(OP mentioned) and all other approaches which create a new index, hope you understand my indentation and it's not to point the flaw in your answer :)

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja Thanks. So if it is not possible in the way I needed, In your opinion, what could be the best way to make sure shard size does not exceed let's say 20GB, and in case of more data index adds new shard?

Comment: ASM are able to do this. You can set a maximum size per shard before rollup